# Ubuntu Guest on VirtualBox on MacOS ping does not work, nslookup works perfectly

Tags: ubuntu, mac, virtualbox, dns, ping

I have an Ubuntu guest -- more precisely [Yahoo Cloud VM](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/posts/2010/06/hadoop_020s_virtualmachine/) on Virtualbox on the top of MacOS. I have configured VirtualBox to serve internet connection to the guest using NAT. Ubuntu uses dhcp to get IP (10.0.2.15) and the IP of my DNS server (in /etc/resolv.conf I find the correct IP - 192.168.1.1 - it is IP of my router used by MacOS). So it seems that everything works fine, however when I try to *ping google.com*  I get error that the host was not found (apt-get does not work either). In the same time, *nslookup* resolves google.com without any problems using 192.168.1.1. Does anybody experience such a situation?

ifconfig output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.) Can you do a traceroute?
traceroute 8.8.8.8

2.) Can you give me the output of ifconfig?
ifconfig

3.) I experienced a lot of network related troubles using VirtualBox 3 on Mac OS X. Upgrade to Version 4 if you are still using the old one.

Comment: 1. I have tracepath not traceroute. Tracepath works with IP, 2. You will find it in the post 3. I use VirtualBox 4